# Filter/Parameter in VB

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2005, report-viewer2010

I once search on Google on how to make a parameter for `Report Viewer` in VB and I got [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0DtlVTGD0EI).

So, I followed the step-by-step process on how to do it. Everything seems fine but after I make a parameter on one value which has a MONEY DATA TYPE on my `SQL` `Database`.

Without having that value(one with MONEY DATA TYPE) this is the result :

[image: Result]

But this it the error if I add it up :

[image]

This is the codes that I used for parameter:

[image]

and I did this too so I can apply that parameter to make a `PRINT` using `Report Viewer` :

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        printall.Show()
        printall.txtID.Text = txtID.Text
        printall.txtFname.Text = txtpFName.Text
        printall.txtLname.Text = txtPLname.Text
        printall.txtMI.Text = txtMI.Text
        printall.txtSex.Text = txtSex.Text
        printall.txtStatus.Text = txtStatus.Text
        printall.txtTelNo.Text = txtTel.Text
        printall.txtDocID.Text = txtPDoc.Text
        printall.txtStreetNo.Text = txtStreetNo.Text
        printall.txtStreetName.Text = txtStreetName.Text
        printall.txtProvince.Text = txtProvince.Text
        printall.txtCity.Text = txtCity.Text
        printall.txtBrgy.Text = txtBrgy.Text
        printall.txtFnameKIN.Text = txtFNameKIN.Text
        printall.txtLnameKIN.Text = txtLNameKIN.Text
        printall.txtmiKIN.Text = txtMIKIN.Text
        printall.txtRELATION.Text = txtRelationKIN.Text
        printall.txtTotalDue.Text = txtTotalDue.Text
    End Sub
```

How to fix it? How to add the TotalDue to report viewer? Can anyone help me with this one?